# Error while creating spatial index on geogarphy column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database, spatial-index

I used the following code to create geography column using latitude, longitude

```
alter table [locate].[dbo].[BFLGeocodedResult] add geographyColumn as geography::STGeomFromText
('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),[Final Longitude])+' '+convert(varchar(20),[Final Latitude])+')',4326)
```

Also created Clustered Index and then tried to create spatial index using the below query

```
       CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [BFLGeocodedResult_sidx] ON [locate].[dbo].[BFLGeocodedResult]
(
    geographyColumn
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (
BOUNDING_BOX =(-90, -180, 90, 180))
```

when I run the above query I get the error

```
Cannot create primary xml, selective xml or spatial index 'BFLGeocodedResult_sidx' on table 'locate.dbo.BFLGeocodedResult', column 'geographyColumn', because the column is computed.
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify the exact version of SQL Server in use.

Answer (score 1):

You create a **computed column** in your alter table statement. Consider creating a geography column and then update (populate) the column with your [Final Longitude] and [Final Latitude] data.